# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The namespace property is required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read and write parquet files as mentioned in spring data hadoop documentation and I got the following error

> Error creating bean with name 'datasetRepositoryFactory' defined in
>   class path resource [com/example/demo/DatasetConfig.class]: Invocation
>   of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The namespace property is required

1. **Reference Project in spring boot**
   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/dataset

   2. **Writing data into Parquet Spring data hadoop** - https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#springandhadoop-store

   DataSetConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
    @ImportResource("hadoop-context.xml")
    public class DatasetConfig {
        private @Autowired org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopConfiguration;
          @Bean 
          public DatasetRepositoryFactory datasetRepositoryFactory() {
          DatasetRepositoryFactory datasetRepositoryFactory = new
          DatasetRepositoryFactory();
          datasetRepositoryFactory.setConf(hadoopConfiguration);
          datasetRepositoryFactory.setBasePath("/tmp"); return
          datasetRepositoryFactory; 
    }
  @Bean 
      public DataStoreWriter<FileInfo> dataStoreWriter() { 
      return new AvroPojoDatasetStoreWriter<FileInfo>(FileInfo.class,
      datasetRepositoryFactory(), fileInfoDatasetDefinition()); }

    @Bean
    public  DatasetOperations datasetOperations() {
        DatasetTemplate datasetOperations = new DatasetTemplate();
        datasetOperations.setDatasetDefinitions(Arrays.asList(fileInfoDatasetDefinition()));
        datasetOperations.setDatasetRepositoryFactory(datasetRepositoryFactory());
        return datasetOperations;
    }

    @Bean
    public  DatasetDefinition fileInfoDatasetDefinition() {
        DatasetDefinition definition = new DatasetDefinition();
        definition.setFormat(Formats.PARQUET.getName());
        definition.setTargetClass(FileInfo.class);
        definition.setAllowNullValues(false);
        return definition;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ParquetReaderApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private DatasetOperations datasetOperations;

    private DataStoreWriter<FileInfo> writer;

    private long count;

    @Autowired
    public  void setDatasetOperations(DatasetOperations datasetOperations) {
        this.datasetOperations = datasetOperations;
    }


      @Autowired 
      public void setDataStoreWriter(DataStoreWriter dataStoreWriter) {
      this.writer = dataStoreWriter;
      }

    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ParquetReaderApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public  void run(String... strings) {
        String fileDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        System.out.println("Processing " + fileDir + " ...");
        File f = new File(fileDir);
        try {
            processFile(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StoreException("Error writing FileInfo", e);
        } finally {
            close();
        }
        countFileInfoEntries();
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

    private  void processFile(File file) throws IOException {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                processFile(f);
            }
        } else {
            if (++count % 10000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Writing " + count + " ...");
            }
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.getName(), file.getParent(), (int)file.length(), file.lastModified());
            writer.write(fileInfo);
        }
    }
```

Expected result -

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/*
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - spring supergroup          0 2014-06-09 17:09 /user/spring/fileinfo/.metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 spring supergroup   13824695 2014-06-09 17:10 /user/spring/fileinfo/6876f250-010a-404a-b8c8-0ce1ee759206.avro
```

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no `namespace` available to `DatasetRepositoryFactory` so set the `namespace`

**public void setNamespace(java.lang.String namespace)** [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/hadoop/store/dataset/DatasetRepositoryFactory.html#setNamespace(java.lang.String))

> Namespace to use. Defaults to no namespace ("default" used for Kite SDK API)

```
@Bean 
public DatasetRepositoryFactory datasetRepositoryFactory() {
      DatasetRepositoryFactory datasetRepositoryFactory = new
      DatasetRepositoryFactory();
      datasetRepositoryFactory.setConf(hadoopConfiguration);
      datasetRepositoryFactory.setBasePath("/tmp"); 
      datasetRepositoryFactory.setNamespace("default"); 
      return datasetRepositoryFactory;
```